# What are the best builds for a Carrier Sentinel?

Tags: ps4, warframe

I have a mid-level **Carrier** and want to know a good build, that makes it attack and pick up items at the same time or close-to. I've checked the wiki but it wasn't very helpful.
It uses **Sweeper** as well so builds for that are also appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't really care about my sentinel's dps so I tossed my dethcube's dethrifle onto my carrier. I use the steel fiber, regeneration (?), shield mod, rifle firing speed, vacuum, and the mods that have a chance to reduce enemy hp (can't remember off the top of my head). IF you want bonus dps, I think your best bet is to use the reduc hp/armor combinations with increased status chance (not that difficult with the re-release of the Cicero mods and the mods you get from whatever event is going on right now).

Comment: Um that isn't very helpful at ALL.

Comment: Well what do you want to do? It's a pretty generic question.

Answer (score 1):

One key difference between sentinels is their attack range. They all have different effective ranges where they start shooting enemies, Carrier has a relatively short range at 5m. The DethCube has a range of 15m, so using the Deth Machine Rifle on the Carrier is pointless given the spool up of that gun means the enemy will be on you before the sentinel can react.

So for Carrier I'd definitely carry on with the Sweeper shotgun, it's impact damage is great at knocking back enemies that get within 5m to you, giving you great protection against charging foes.

Mod-wise, fit what you can on your sentinel, the only must have mods I would say is "Coolant Leak" and "Fired Up". One gives you another layer of protection against charging enemies and the other increases the damage of your sentinel weapon the more it shoots.

With that in mind, apart from the usual DPS/elemental mods for the Sweeper, I like to increase the mag size so that "Fired Up" can do more overheat damage.

For reference, this is what my beloved [Carrier](http://goo.gl/kvRTh8) and [Sweeper](http://goo.gl/JqHnl2) look like.

Comment: +1 this. Sweeper is undoubtedly the best Sentinel weapon, alongside Stinger (for sniping) and Prime Laser Rifle (mid range).  With the right mods,  it can one shot most enemies late into the game, and better yet, has unlimited ammunition.